# A mix of nouns and adjectives joined by a coordinating conjunction

Tags: adjectives, nouns, coordination

Is it grammatical to coordinate adjectives and nouns as follows?

> Steve is a helpful classmate, a good friend, and wise when you turn to
>   him.

I have not come across sentences like that, at least in school; maybe I should say I do not remember seeing a construction like the one below whereby you have a mix of nouns and adjectives joined by a coordinating conjunction such as "and", "or", or "but".

> **Noun1** is a **noun2**, a **noun3** and **adj1**.
>
> **Steve** is a helpful **office mate**, a good friend, and wise when you turn to him.

Source: made it up

Comment: It's fine. All the coordinates are predicative complements referring to "Steve".

Answer (score 1):

The restriction is not the categories (e.g. *verb, adjective, adverb* etc.), but the **functions** (e.g. *complement, subject, adjunct* etc.) of the expressions. Since they're all complements of the linking verb "is," the coordination is fine.

Note that this sentence ungrammatical by virtue of having an adverb as a complement of a linking verb: **He is **cute and nicely***

Comment: Thanks. I got it, but this makes me want to brush up and read up on two things, complements and the linguistic "word classes?". I was wondering if function is a grammar term. I'll google right away. Thanks once again.

Comment: [category vs function](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/sent-functioncategory.html#hide1)